# TFS WorkItem customisation

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I was wondering is it possible to create a custom validation rule for a control? Let's say I want to restrict users from changing the CompleteTime field in Issue, so that it can't be downvoted? Is there a way to check the current value of the field and allow input of only higher values?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/custom-rules

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/apply-rule-work-item-field?toc=/vsts/work/customize/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/customize/breadcrumb/toc.json

Comment: @John Doe We cannot achieve that based on the existing default rules, see the links provided by Mike above.  Generally, the `CompleteTime` field should be readonly. You can use the **SERVERDEFAULT** rule to get the system time when state changed if needed.